# How to implement AIML in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, artificial-intelligence, expert-system, aiml

AIML files: http://www.alicebot.org/aiml/aaa/
I want to make these AIML files the knowledge base of my Prolog program.
Help me. Thanks in advance.

P.S. Excuse my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

http://pycdep.sourceforge.net contains something AIML-like implemented in prolog.
Maybe it can serve as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consult (rent it from your local library, don't buy the whole book) the following book:

An Introduction to Language Processing with Perl and Prolog
Pierre M. Nugues (Autor)
[Text Book](http://www.amazon.de/Introduction-Language-Processing-Perl-Prolog/dp/354025031X) [image]

Before delving into chart parsers and the like, the book contains two sections that deal with eliza like template matching. The sections are:

```
9.2 Word Spotting and Template Matching  
9.3 Multiword Detection
```

It has Prolog code snipets. The code snipets are not optimized for speed or large volumes, but they show the general idea of the algorithms.

The book is good in computer linguistics, but you might want to consult additional sources for Q&A logic etc..

Best Regards

P.S.: Currently working as well on a Prolog port of a Java/Prolog hybrid extraction pipeline
[CAT](http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=156749127726976)